# dataframeに含まれる、文字列中の数字を取り出したい

Tags: python, pandas

dfにおけるｘには、目的地までの来るまでの移動時間、または徒歩分数が混在しています。
index 2には、徒歩分数が入っています。
車での移動時間が入っている箇所では、「車x(ykm)」という形式になっています。
車の時間のみを取り出し、次のような列に「car_time」という変数名を付けて、dfに追加したいです。

['5','0','27']

現在は以下のような状況です。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['車5(0.8km)', '5', '車27(8.6km)']},
    index=[1, 2, 3])

df['car_time'] = df.apply(lambda i: re.split(r'[^0-9]', i.x), axis=1)
print(df)
#                x            car_time
#    1   車5(0.8km)   [, 5, 0, 8, , , ]
#    2           5                 [5]
#    3  車27(8.6km)  [, 27, 8, 6, , , ]
```

追伸：御陰様で、下記のコマンドで、作成することができました。

```
# 車時間のみを取り出し、欠損値には0をうめる。
df['car_time'] = df.x.str.extract(r'車(\d*)').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これでどうでしょう。 [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) を使いました

```
>>> df
            x
1   車5(0.8km)
2           5
3  車27(8.6km)
>>> df.x.str.extract(r'車(\d*)').fillna(0)
1     5
2     0
3    27
Name: x, dtype: object
>>> df['ans'] = df.x.str.extract(r'車(\d*)').fillna(0)
>>> df
            x ans
1   車5(0.8km)   5
2           5   0
3  車27(8.6km)  27
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変助かりました。